# SQL - Select distinct column without excluding rows

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct, distinct-values

I'm running a query that aggregates sales information by either category or subcategory within some date range.  I was asked to add budget information to it for a report that displays the information fetched by this query.

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(B.TxnDate, "%Y-%m") AS FormattedTxnDate,
    SUM(B.Quantity) AS QuantitySum,
    SUM(B.Quantity * B.Amount) AS Revenue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN B.AverageCost = 0 THEN (B.Quantity * C.PurchaseCost) ELSE (B.Quantity * 
    B.AverageCost) END) AS COGS,
    A.CustomerRefFullName,
    SUM(D.Budget_2018) AS Budget,
    D.Brand, D.Category, D.Subcategory, D.ProductManager, C.VendorRefFullName
FROM
    qb_invoice_info A, qb_invoice_line_info B, qb_item_info C, qb_item_group D
WHERE
    A.TxnID = B.TxnID
AND
    B.Item_ListID = C.ListID
AND
    C.Parent_ListID = D.ListID
AND
    (C.Type = "Inventory" OR C.Type = "InventoryAssembly")
AND
    B.TxnDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP
    BY D.Category, YEAR(B.TxnDate), QUARTER(B.TxnDate)
ORDER
    BY D.Category ASC, YEAR(B.TxnDate) ASC, QUARTER(B.TxnDate) ASC
```

Every subcategory has its own budget amount.  The problem is that some subcategories share all of the same information except for their unique IDs.  A few records might look like this within the qb_item_group table.

```
qb_item_group
id | Category | Subcategory | Budget
------------------------------------
1A | Lights   | DMX         | 4000
1B | Lights   | DMX         | 4000
1C | Lights   | DMX         | 4000
2A | Lights   | Flash       | 5000
3A | Lights   | Bulbs       | 1000
```

In this case, the total budget for lights would be 10,000 because we ignore two of the DMX budgets.  I tried `SUM(DISTINCT D.Budget_2018 AS Budget` earlier today but it failed as I expected because it's only adding unique budget values.  How can I adapt the query I have above so that I can retrieve all sales records by either category or subcategory but still get a total budget that is the sum of all unique subcategories under the parent category?

Comment: ``distinct Subcategory`` with ``group by Category``?

Comment: Please format your SQL so we can actually read it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Fixed, it's MySQL.

Comment: *sigh* MySQL permits non-standard syntax in the `group by` clause and you have fallen into this trap. Under standard rules for grouping you must specify **all** "non-aggregating columns" in the group by clause.

Comment: Can you provide sample data **per table** please (there are 4 tables in your query, so 4 sets of sample data)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  
  DATE_FORMAT(B.TxnDate, "%Y-%m")      AS FormattedTxnDate, 
  SUM(B.Quantity)                      AS QuantitySum,
  SUM(B.Quantity * B.Amount) AS Revenue,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN B.AverageCost = 0 THEN (B.Quantity * C.PurchaseCost) 
      ELSE (B.Quantity * B.AverageCost) 
    END
  )                                    AS COGS, 
  A.CustomerRefFullName, 
  COALESCE(category_budgets.budget, 0) AS budget,
  D.Brand,
  D.Category,
  D.Subcategory,
  D.ProductManager,
  C.VendorRefFullName
FROM 
  qb_invoice_info A, 
  qb_invoice_line_info B, 
  qb_item_info C, 
  qb_item_group D
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT
    a.category,
    SUM(a.budget) as budget
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      category
      budget
    FROM 
      budgets
  ) a
) category_budgets
ON
  category_budgets.category = D.category
WHERE 
  A.TxnID = B.TxnID
AND 
  B.Item_ListID = C.ListID
AND 
  C.Parent_ListID = D.ListID
AND 
  (C.Type = "Inventory" OR C.Type = "InventoryAssembly")
AND 
  B.TxnDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY 
  D.Category, YEAR(B.TxnDate), QUARTER(B.TxnDate)
ORDER BY 
  D.Category ASC, YEAR(B.TxnDate) ASC, QUARTER(B.TxnDate) ASC
;
```

You can left join with the sum of distinct categories and budgets. This will give you all of your output rows desired but will also give you $0 budgets for categories that don't have entries in the budgets table. Good luck!

Comment: This is giving me the error `qb_forecast_import.budgets does not exist`.  There's no separate "budgets" table to handle this.  The budgets for each subcategory are contained within qb_item_group.

Comment: I'm just selecting from an arbitrary table called "budgets" in my subquery...you should change that to be the actual name of the table with schema `id | Category | Subcategory | Budget`